# Difference between ArcObjects SDK for Java and ArcGIS Runtime for Java?

Tags: arcobjects, java, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I would like to develop spatial tools and automate my spatial analysis process (including converting XY into shp, proximity analysis, network analysis, geocoding etc on thousands of files) in Java.

I was wondering if ArcGIS runtime sdk for Java can do the task or do I need ArcObjects sdk for Java.

I can see that they are two different things but I am really confused what is the difference between them and which one does what?

I am also looking for some tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/guide/guide.htm), you can write standalone applications, viewing / editing mostly [ArcGIS Online](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline) data

With the [ArcObjects java SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html), you can do almost everything ArcMap can do. In fact, ArcMap and ArcCatalog seems to be written with ArcObjects.

With ArcObjects, you can even add functionality to ArcMap by adding toolbar buttons and developping multiple [extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#/Developing_extensions/000100000391000000/) types.

So, if you need to do complex analysis on multiple files, ArcObjects java SDK seems the way to go. In addition, I thinkg the sdk is included with ArcGIS for Desktop, no extra licence needed.

You can always take a look at [python scripting](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000001000000) to automate your processes